# How to solve this simultaneous equation of implicit equation?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Can someone show me step by step how to solve these simultaneous equations?

$$x^2-y^2-4xy+4x-1=0$$
$$2x^2-2y^2+2xy+4y+2=0$$

Comment: Hint : For a start, multiply the first equation with $2$ and subtract the equations. Not quite "completing the square", but "completing a term of the form $a(x+m)(y+n)$"

Comment: You could just as well divide the second equation by 2 and subtract them

Comment: @user35508 In fact, I did not notice that we only have even coefficients :)

Comment: @Muhammad Khairul Ikhwan: Are the numbers x,y required to be real?

Comment: @quasi yes . Any idea ?

Comment: The following steps work (although somewhat laborious): (1) Divide out the factor of 2 in the second equation; (2) subtract the equations; (3) solve for y in terms of x; (4) Substitute for y in one of the equations; (5) clear denominators; (6) Apply the rational root test; (7) Using long division, remove linear factors corresponding to rational roots; (8) If only a quadratic remains, test the discriminant. If negative, reject the quadratic, else try to factor it, or use the quadratic formula.

Comment: @Muhammad Khairul Ikhwan: Is it a HW problem, or from a book, or from a contest exam?

Comment: @quasi It is a HW problem

Comment: @Muhammad Khairul Ikhwan: My hints will work, although there might be an easier way. What is the level of the course?

Comment: The two hyperbolas are concentric, so you can simplify the equations a bit—eliminate the linear terms—by translating the origin to their common center. You can find that center by setting the partial derivatives of the l.h.s. to zero and solving for $x$ and $y$. Just remember to translate your solutions back when you’re done.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your equations with following two functions

$$\begin{gathered}
  \phi \left( {x,y} \right) = {x^2} - {y^2} - 4 \cdot x \cdot y + 4 \cdot x - 1 \hfill \\
  \psi \left( {x,y} \right) = 2 \cdot {x^2} - 2 \cdot {y^2} + 2 \cdot x \cdot y + 4 \cdot y + 2 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Then we have to found the zeros like so

$$\begin{gathered}
  \phi \left( {x,y} \right) = 0 \hfill \\
  \psi \left( {x,y} \right) = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Calculating

$$\phi \left( {x,y} \right) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \psi \left( {x,y} \right) = 0$$

we get

$$ - 5 \cdot x \cdot y + 4 \cdot x - 2 \cdot y - 2 = 0$$

which leads us to

$$y = \frac{{4 \cdot x - 2}}{{5 \cdot x + 2}}$$

Putting this in $$\phi \left( {x,y} \right) = 0$$

we get

$$\phi \left( {x,y} \right) = \phi \left( {x,\frac{{4 \cdot x - 2}}{{5 \cdot x + 2}}} \right) = \frac{{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {5x - 1} \right)\left( {5{x^2} + 4x + 8} \right)}}{{{{\left( {5x + 2} \right)}^2}}} = 0$$

Now we see, we have two pairs of real solution

$$\begin{gathered}
  x =  - 1 \Rightarrow y = 2 \hfill \\
  x = \frac{1}{5} \Rightarrow y =  - \frac{2}{5} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

These coordinates are the intersection points for two hyperboles

[image]

And that's all.

Comment: There are two more solutions $x=-\frac25 + \frac65 i, y = \frac45 + \frac35 i$ and its complex conjugate.

Comment: @Marc I know this. It's the third factor from factorisation, which leads to complex solution.
Only real valued solustion are asked for here in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution method has been described in various comments: eliminate some terms by fiddling with the terms a bit and taking a linear combination of the equations, solve the resulting equation for one of the variables in terms of the other, then back-substitute into the original equations. With a pair of distinct conic sections as you have here, you’ll get anywhere from 0 to 4 solutions.

Before plunging into this general procedure, it’s often a good idea to look at the specific problem for potential short-cuts or simplifications. In this case, the geometry of the problem gives us a bit of help. We’ll take one of the suggestions immediately and divide the second equation by $2$. The two equations represent hyperbolas, as can be seen by computing their discriminants: $(-4)^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-1)=20$ and $1^2-2\cdot1\cdot(-1)=3$. Now find their centers, which you can do by either remembering the formula for that or computing the gradient and solving for $x$ and $y$: $$\nabla(x^2-y^2-4xy+4x-1)=\langle2x-4y+4,-2y-4x\rangle=0,$$ so $(x,y)=(-2/5,4/5)$. For the second equation, we get $$\nabla(x^2-y^2+xy+2y+1)=\langle2x+y,-2y+x+2\rangle=0$$ and so again $(x,y)=(-2/5,4/5)$. This is a bit of luck as it allows us to eliminate the linear terms in both equations with a translation. Making the substitutions $x\to x'-2/5$ and $y\to y'+4/5$ produces the system $$x'^2-4x'y'-y'^2-\frac95=0 \\ x'^2+x'y'-y'^2+\frac95=0.$$ Note that you don’t have to go though tedious algebraic manipulations to arrive at these equations. Translating the origin to the center of a conic eliminates the linear terms from its general equation while leaving the quadratic terms alone; the new constant term is just the original expression applied to the two offsets. E.g., the constant term of the first equation after translation is $$\left(-\frac25\right)^2-\left(\frac45\right)^2-4\left(-\frac25\right)\left(\frac45\right)+4\left(-\frac25\right)-1=-\frac95.$$ This looks promising. Subtract the first equation from the second to eliminate both $x'^2$ and $y'^2$, giving $$5x'y'+\frac{18}5=0$$ and then solve for either $x'$ or $y'$ as you see fit. Let’s take $y'=-18/25x'$. Substituting this back into either of the translated equations gives $$x'^2+{27\over25}-{324\over625x'^2}=0,$$ a quartic equation in $x'$, but not to worry: all of the exponents are even, so you can treat it as a quadratic equation, which I hope you can solve without further assistance from us (you should get two real and two complex roots).

Once you have solutions to the translated equations, translate them back to get the solutions to the original equations, i.e., add $-2/5$ and $4/5$, respectively, to the values of $x'$ and $y'$ that you’ve computed.